# Powershell, Set-Acl, How to sort users to folders and apply permissions once

Tags: powershell, csv, permissions

I am trying to apply permissions on a very large folder tree (Multiple servers/shares). The script I have works, but is not efficent and is taking too long to run because its setting it on a per-user and per-folder basis.

I have an csv file with three Columns UserID, Path and offset. Example Below

```
Domain\OneUser,\\\Server\Share\1\2\3\4\5\6,5<BR>
Domain\TwoUser,\\\Server\Share\1\2\3\4\5\6,5<BR>
Domain\OneUser,\\\Server\Share\1\2\A\B\C\D,5<BR>
Domain\ThreeUser,\\\Server\Share\1\2\A\B\C,5<BR>
Domain\TwoUser,\\\Server\Share\1\2\3\4\5,5
```

The script reads in the file and then sets the permissions for each object using an offset. In this example the offset would be 5 which would make the script stop at 1. It also ignores the last folder in the path.

In the case above, OneUser would be set on 5,4,3,2,1. Then TwoUser would be set on 5,4,3,2,1. Then OneUser would be set on C,B,A,2,1. Some of this is duplicating work as in the 3rd line (setting on 2 and 1 after its already been set).

Instead of setting permissions on each individual folder, I need to group it together so that it would set it like this instead of setting permissions 23 times which it could be done in 8.

```
OneUser,Twouser on 5,4,3<BR>
OneUser on C<BR>
OneUser,ThreeUser on B,A<BR>
OneUser,TwoUser,ThreeUser on 2,1
```

I am looking to do one of two things:

1. Export the list to a csv so it looks like:

   OneUser;Twouser,\\Server\Share\1\2\3\4\5
   OneUser;Twouser,\\Server\Share\1\2\3\4\

And so on.

Or using the piece of the script below, for each unique set of folders/users, modify the $objACE and $objACL to contain unique users per folder

```
$objACE1 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(**Domain\OneUser**, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType<BR>) 
$objACE2 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(**Domain\TwoUser**, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE1)<BR>
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE2)
```

Essentially I need to add all of the objects per-folder before calling the Set-Acl per folder so I am only applying permissions once per folder. I also need to exclude the end folder (Where permissions already exist) and to tell it where to stop.

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this easily?

This part of the script is the most import and contains all of the settings that I need to set the proper permissions.

```
#parameters for setting proper traverse/list access to 'This folder only' of parent tree
$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadAndExecute,Synchronize" 

#turns off inheritance for this permission
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 

#ensures 'this folder only' setting of permissions - will not force propogation
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

#specifies that this is an allow access type
$objType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

#reads in group/user from csv file to grant permissions for
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($UserName) 

#builds the new access control to program on parent folders
$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

#reads in current access control of current parent folder
$objACL = Get-ACL $Container 

#adds the access rule to current access controls of the current parent folder
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 

#writes out screen feedback on current status of the script
write-host Setting permissions on $Container for $Username

#Sets access controls on each applicable folder.  This does not affect existing permissions, only adds to them.
Set-ACL $container $objACL
```

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to achieve by doing this? What do you need that "offset" for? Why can't you simply set permissions on the folder 5 levels up and leave the rest to inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my suggestion is to make a hashtable to better organize your information. Make your keys the folders, and the values the users that need access to that folder. By parsing the folders on each line of your CSV and iterating through them you can build your folder list. Then for each folder check if it is in the hashtable and add the user to that key, or create a new key if needed. Then loop through folders, and for each folder add an ACL rule to the ACL object for each user that is listed for that folder in the hashtable. Here is the code I would use to do that:

```
$Import = Import-Csv "C:\Path\To\File.csv"
$AllPaths = @{}
$Import | ?{$_.path -match "^(\\.*?)\\[^\\]*$"}|%{
    $Subs = $Matches[1].split('\')|Where{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)}
    $RootPath = $Subs[0..($Subs.count - $_.Offset - 1)]
    For($i=[int]($Subs.count - 1);$i -ge ($Subs.count - $_.Offset);$i--){
        $CurPath = "\\{0}\{1}" -f ($RootPath -join '\'),($Subs[($RootPath.count)..$i] -join '\')
        If($AllPaths.Keys -contains $CurPath -and $AllPaths[$CurPath] -notcontains $_.User){
            $AllPaths[$CurPath]+=$_.User
        }elseif($AllPaths.Keys -notcontains $CurPath){
            $AllPaths.Add($CurPath,@($_.User))
        }
    }
}

ForEach($Container in $AllPaths.Keys){

    #parameters for setting proper traverse/list access to 'This folder only' of parent tree
    $colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadAndExecute,Synchronize" 

    #turns off inheritance for this permission
    $InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 

    #ensures 'this folder only' setting of permissions - will not force propogation
    $PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

    #specifies that this is an allow access type
    $objType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

    #reads in current access control of current parent folder
    $objACL = Get-ACL $Container 

    #Add an access rule for each user needing access to this folder to the ACL before writing the ACL back to the folder
    ForEach($UserName in $AllPaths[$Container]){

        #reads in group/user from csv file to grant permissions for
        $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($UserName) 

        #builds the new access control to program on parent folders
        $objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

        #adds the access rule to current access controls of the current parent folder
        $objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 
    }

    #writes out screen feedback on current status of the script
    write-host "Setting permissions on $Container for $($AllPaths[$Container].Values -join ", ")"

    #Sets access controls on each applicable folder.  This does not affect existing permissions, only adds to them.
    Set-ACL $container $objACL 
}
```

Using your example data I was able to compile the following list of folders, and the associated users that would need access to those folders:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $AllPaths|ft -AutoSize

Name                     Value                                             
----                     -----                                             
\\Server\Share\1\2\3\4\5 {Domain\OneUser, Domain\TwoUser}                  
\\Server\Share\1\2\A     {Domain\OneUser, Domain\ThreeUser}                
\\Server\Share\1\2       {Domain\OneUser, Domain\TwoUser, Domain\ThreeUser}
\\Server\Share\1\2\A\B   {Domain\OneUser, Domain\ThreeUser}                
\\Server\Share\1         {Domain\OneUser, Domain\TwoUser, Domain\ThreeUser}
\\Server\Share\1\2\3\4   {Domain\OneUser, Domain\TwoUser}                  
\\Server\Share\1\2\3     {Domain\OneUser, Domain\TwoUser}                  
\\Server\Share\1\2\A\B\C {Domain\OneUser}                                  
\\Server\Share           {Domain\ThreeUser, Domain\TwoUser}
```